# What are the benefits of the different weapons in survival mode?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

I have started playing MW3 recently and have completed 13 rounds in Resistance map. I have been using the Assault Riffle ACR 6.8. What kind of weapons I should use for survival mode where I can get more bang for my buck?

Comment: This depends heavily on your play style.  The only possible objective interpretation I see is damage per round, which you can see yourself from the weapon stats.  I don't think this is a good question.

Comment: Besides damage, there are other things like reload time, accuracy and sprint speed. As agent86 pointed out, LMGs are less useful in certain situations like running away from juggernauts. As I have mentioned in my question, I just started off playing MW3. Bear with me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I play survival, I tend to "live off the land" and take weapons off of dead enemy soldiers instead of buying weapons at the shop.  In Resistance in particular, it's pretty easy to set up shop in the center house, like I explained here:

[What is best sniper position on Resistance in Spec Ops: Survival mode?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49145/what-is-best-sniper-position-on-resistance-in-spec-ops-survival-mode)

Remember that you can also carry two primary weapons in Survival - so if enemies are using AK-47's and ammo for that is plentiful on the ground, you can use that gun alongside another AR that you've purchased or found in an earlier round.  Between rounds you can go back and just buy ammo, or pick up upgrades for these weapons if you prefer them.

Having 2 ARs means that if you empty a clip and there's still a lot of guys to shoot, you can switch to your off-hand AR and continue firing faster than you could've reloaded.

I don't tend to like LMGs or SMGs, the LMGs take too long to reload, and the SMGs do pitiful damage against enemies in the later rounds.  You might find them useful, depending on your strategy and preferences, however.

Not buying weapons means that you have more cash left over for other things, such as sentry guns, squads of AI helpers, and air support to deal with Juggernauts and other difficult situations.

Here is the weapon list and their rankings:
[image]
[Larger size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDLU4.jpg)

Comment: A solid answer, but I disagree with your comments about LMGs. At waves 30+ an LMG is almost a necessity.

Answer (score 1):

I have gotten to LvL 39-40 on Bakarra which is the hardest diffuclty by using the best combination that I have seen, along with other people I know that have gotten past lvl 65 using this combo. Use the L86 LMG, which reloads pretty damn fast for an lmg and allows you to have the ammo you need for the higher levels along with the power to chop to the helicopters if you manage to use your predators or whatever you use. Secondly purchase the sleight of hand perk if you're lvl 50 and a grip and a red dot sight instead of a holographic sight which will also increase your visuals for the game.

The second weapon you will need to save up for is the AA-12, it does run out of ammo fast but will take out a juggernaut in 2 clips (sleight of hand allows you to shoot off 12 rounds in about 2-3 seconds if that) up to about lvl 40 since that is as far as me and my buddys have gone to without dying for one stupid reason or another or running out of ammo due to poor planning. Buy a grip for this shotgun as it will increase your accurarcy when shooting the juggs. Use flashbangs and if you have a partner alternate.

Good tips to use through this is do not purchase the explosive turrents they will kill you more than help. Use C4, about 7-8 will kill a single jugg up to lvl 28 if I'm not mistaken so thats one less you have to deal with and 2 less if your partner kills with a predator and none if you then shoot your predator off and kill one. Also remember using shield squads doesnt help you kill people but it does give you time to prep after the round starts or during a road when you need to reload or get out of the Red vision stage from taking too much damage. I would advise that you and your partner set up claymores up the steps in Bakarra or in resistance (bakarra the 2 story next to the grenade, turret, armor pelican case.). This will allow you to see the jugg and blow up your C4 and your partner to shoot a predator off without being attacked by those damned C4 dogs.

Comment: Totally agree on the L86 and C4. Your AA-12 experience is interesting, I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

i have been trying to figure out the best guns for MW3 survival and from what i have learned the best gun to use is the MP7 and the MK46. MP7 can take down a regular juggernaut with less than one mag if you aim for the head. shooting anywhere else would take 2-4 mags. The MK46 can take down an armored juggernaut with only two mags. I got to wave 67 in seatown with a this set-up. Sleight of hand would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to say l86 lmg and any gun that the enemy uses. If they are using ak-47s pick one up as it saves time any money.

Perks:

- Slight of Hand
- Self Revive

Equipment:

- C4 (10)
- Claymores (10)
- Auto or grenade sentries depending on the location
- Flashbangs

Air support:

- Riot shield team
- Predator missile

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I like to do:
Kill the first man and then pick up his weapon. Then finish off the rest with your pistol, picking up all of the ammo as it drops.  By this time you should have a half sock(?) gun.  Next, switch out your pistol when a new gun gets dropped, instead of buying a new weapon. Continue doing this throughout the playthrough, switching out older guns for newer guns, and by about round 25 you should have enough to buy 2 LMGs.

Answer (score 1):

What me and my partner do is buy everything as soon as we have enough money to get it. That means at wave 6 we are buying our first lmg and by wave 12 we have sleight of hand. The reason we do this is because with a lot of ammo it is easier to concentrate on getting rampages and kill streaks and also by buying all the expensive things first by the time we reach level 38 we have about 40-50k a piece (get rich or die tryin) and that allows for us to properly prepare for the harder rounds with predators, rioters, and air strikes without breaking the bank.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, on the earlier levels, just use whatever weapons the enemies are dropping, allowing you to build up a bit of a buffer of cash that you will need later on.

Enemies get progressively more hitpoints as the waves go on, so by around Wave 15+ you will need to carry at least one LMG to cut down all the troops they throw at you.

By Wave 35+, it's virtually very, very difficult to kill all the enemies without you running out of ammo, unless you carry *two* LMGs.

By Wave 50, I'm fairly certain it's impossible to proceed without two LMGs.

Comment: Largely depends on the map and weapons your partner uses. I've made 51 on Seatown with L86 and FAD. Mostly because my partner didn't use a FAD so all the dropped ammo was available to me. Generally I use L86 and MG36, but it's about keeping steady points for C4, claymores etc.

Answer (score 0):

The buying everything when you have the money is easiest for helicopter and Juggernauts. When using LMGs, you don't have to move; you can throw frags, sit and shoot at his head or your partner can go to the back of him. Or you and your partner can take turns shooting his middle armor plate easily taking a Juggernaut out. You can get easy practice by doing underground - a helicopter comes at wave 6, then a Juggernaut at wave 10, 2 at wave 15,and 3 at wave 20 and so on.